# Proper way to test a null objective-C string in Swift?

Tags: swift

I've got an Objective-C framework which exports the following class:

```
@interface NIDIdentifiedNumberItem : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString          *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString          *address;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString          *number;
...
```

I read that Objective-C pointers automatically get converted to swift optionals, however that is not what I am observing:

[image]

and the following code does not produce the intended consequence:

```
if item.address != nil
{
   // code will execute
```

How should the check for Objective-C null pointers be performed in Swift?

The object is populated thus in the framework:

```
- (NSArray*) identifiedNumbers {
    NSMutableArray* numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     NIDIdentifiedNumberItem* item = [[NIDIdentifiedNumberItem alloc] init];
     item.name = "Something";
     item.address = nil;
     etc.
    [numbers addObject:item];
    return numbers;
```

And obtained in Swift:

```
   var identifiedNumbers = []
   ...
   identifiedNumbers =  NIDModel.singleton().identifiedNumbers()
   ...
   let item = identifiedNumbers[indexPath.row]
```

I also observed the following:

```
    let a = item.address
    if a != nil {
    }
    if let b = item.address
    {
    }
```

Both of these if statements will execute. After the assignment a is of type String!! while b is of type String!. Why are they different and why are both if statements evaluating to true?

Comment: You're not providing enough context to make the problem reproducible.

Comment: Updated with full relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
var identifiedNumbers = []
```

You have not declared what this is an array *of*. Therefore, *faute de mieux*, it is typed as an NSArray. But an NSArray is of no known element type. Therefore, when you say

```
let item = identifiedNumbers[indexPath.row]
```

you get an AnyObject. Therefore, when you say `item.address` you are not *fetching* the address; you are asking whether this unknown thing even *has* an `address` property. That is why it is typed as `String!!` — the first `!` is because  if this thing does have an `address` it will be an Optional wrapping a String, and the second one is because the whole notion of having an `address` property gets that result wrapped in another Optional.

As it turns out, this unknown thing does have an `address` property, so `item.address` is not `nil`. But if you unwrap *that*, *now* you have an Optional String, so now you can see whether it is in fact `nil`. It is:

```
if item.address != nil {
    if item.address! != nil {
        // it is nil, this won't execute
    }
}
```

If you had typed your `identifiedNumbers` properly, as a `[NIDIdentifiedNumberItem]`, you would never have fallen into these insane and unnecessary difficulties. You can use Objective-C's lightweight generics to help make that happen automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

That converts as an optional, assuming you haven't been playing around with `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN/END`. So you can:

```
if let address = item.address
{
    print("Address is \(address)")
}
```

If you have told the compiler to assume non-null then the type exposed to Swift won't appear to be optional. So it can never be `nil` as far as Swift is concerned.

Comment: You might add a `where` clause to this to check the string length as well: `if let address = item.address where address.length > 0`

Comment: I've added all the relevant code. I've not changed any of the Xcode options BTW

Comment: if let address = item.address where address.characters.count > 0  will result in the "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error.